# SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface throws an 500 error on BadCredentialsException

Tags: php, security, symfony

I'm really new to the topic of security customization symfony, following the guides I've created a simple way to authenticate my API.

in case the user dont sent a special header with the token the app throws a

```php
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\PreAuthenticatedToken;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
//...

public function createToken(Request $request, $providerKey)
{
    if (!$request->headers->has(self::API_TOKEN)) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException('No API key found');
    }

    return new PreAuthenticatedToken('anon.', $request->headers->get(self::API_TOKEN), $providerKey);
}
```

i dont know exactly what should return symfony, but i know must be a 401 error and not a 500. how i can handle this, I need write my own `SimplePreAuthenticationListener`? As i read the idea behind `Simple*AuthenticatorInterface`is [avoid that](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-customize-the-security-features-with-ease)

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing *Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface* in your Authenticator class

```
public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return new Response("Authentication Failed.", 403);
}
```